# Getting the most recent version of a file kept by archive.org

Tags: rest, web-scraping, archive

I have a set of harvested atom feeds. Some of them have a few years, and some of the posts link to images that are no longer there.

Is there any way to get the most recent version kept by the [Way Back Machine](http://archive.org/)?

I know I can do it manually, but I'd like to automate the process. archive.org provides a restful API, but as far as I could find out it doesn't seem to provide the specific calls that I need. I suppose I could always fallback to web-scraping, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. To get the latest version of a file you just have to `GET` the URL (don't forget to check that the HTTP status code is `200`):

`http://web.archive.org/web/form-submit.jsp?type=replay&url=<file_url>`